What was the reason to require MSDOS.SYS to be at least 1024 bytes in size?
Similarly to CP/M, the kernel of MS-DOS up to version 6.22 was split into two files: the (DOS-)BIOS, carrying the name IO.SYS (or IBMBIO.COM), and the BDOS, named MSDOS.SYS (or IBMDOS.COM).  With MS-DOS 7.0, which is the version incorporated into Windows 95, the BIOS and BDOS were combined into a single file containing the whole DOS kernel, kept in the file named IO.SYS, while the file name MSDOS.SYS was repurposed for a text-based configuration file.  The two files could also be sometimes found under the names WINBOOT.SYS and WINBOOT.INI, respectively.
The version of MSDOS.SYS that Windows 9x places on the hard disk carries this comment:

;The following lines are required for compatibility with other programs.
;Do not remove them (MSDOS.SYS needs to be >1024 bytes).


followed by 19 lines of comments, each consisting mostly of “x” characters.
Microsoft Knowledge Base articles Q118579 and Q129998 seem to imply this ballast was primarily intended to pacify anti-virus software:

For example, if an anti-virus program detects that the Msdos.sys file is less than 1024 bytes in length, the program may assume that the Msdos.sys file is infected with a virus.

But this explanation makes little sense.  One would expect an infected file to be larger, or the same size, as the original – and since MSDOS.SYS is a configuration file and not an executable, there is no way it could be infected with anything (of course, software written before Windows 9x was released could presumably assume otherwise, but it’s still a strange to assume a file is infected because it is too small).  And the MSDOS.SYS file of previous versions of MS-DOS was much larger than just 1024 bytes.  Even as early as PC DOS 1.0, IBMDOS.COM was already 6400 bytes in size, and it only kept growing.
Microsoft didn’t always conform to this constraint themselves anyway – using the FORMAT /S command of Windows 9x resulted in an MSDOS.SYS file consisting of a single comment line, ;FORMAT.  The Emergency Boot Disk version similarly consists of only one line, ;W95EBD or ;W98EBD.  They might have not bothered even with that, as the MS-DOS 7.x kernel itself boots to a command line just fine even without any MSDOS.SYS file present (seemingly contradicting what Q118579 claims).
So what was the real reason MSDOS.SYS had to be artificially inflated?

My suspicion is that it probably has something to do with the file system layout requirements that used to be placed on kernel files in much earlier DOS versions, but I could not find anything specific.

As regards possible virus detection and 'not making sense' -- I don't recall any requirement for anti-virus implementors to possess sense.  Possibly Microsoft found at least one major AV that required size >= 1K and decided it wasn't worth fighting.

@dave Indeed they often didn’t… but this fails to even pretend to make sense, which I think AV vendors would pay more attention to.

Anyway, searching for clues, I found https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66530/, https://www.os2museum.com/wp/dos-boot-hang-update/, https://old.reddit.com/r/vintagecomputing/comments/12vj5ta/extracting_msdos_7/jhbxd7u/, https://microsoft.public.win98.gen-discussion.narkive.com/AlyDlIqZ/msdos-sys.

Re 'pretend to make sense' -- I read it as 'we at MS found an existing AV that made this stupid assumption, we won't name it, but we will make our file compatible so Windows 95 does not get the blame for the AV's error'.  Me, I would have named names.

@dave I figured that much. But I still can’t imagine how that conversation must have looked like on the AV vendor side: “We’re going to check the size of MSDOS.SYS, and if it’s too small, it probably means the file is infected!” “Brilliant! …But how does it work?” “I dunno.” So I suspect the anti-virus claim is actually a red herring and the true reason is something else.

It's possible that the problem wasn't an explicit check in the AV software, but an implicit assumption or outright bug that happened to be triggered by a short MSDOS.SYS. For example, if it read 1K from the file, didn't check the result, and started acting based on what happened to be in memory where the file would have been read in if it had been 1K or more. Or if it did arithmetic on the file size which blew up with a file size below 1K.

[This started as a comment, but after using the third box I moved it here]
As @dave indicates, 'security' software and sense does not belong in one sentence without negating either.
Some Background
Maybe relevant here: MSDOS.SYS is not a self-contained file - or at least it wasn't, early on. The boot sector always loads BIOS and DOS as one binary blob. For PC-DOS 1.0 that's a 20 sector (10 KiB) streak loaded. BIOS does not load DOS, but rather jumps to an external label (SYSINIT ?) within MS's init code linked to BIOS together with DOS (there's more to it). This in turn means that DOS can start with any arbitrary data, as the entry points are defined during linking and stored within the BIOS part.
With that in mind, hiding a virus's location pointer on disk using the second root directory entry becomes a very appealing idea. After all, the entry which is always there, always hidden, but never used (except for name checking) is a pretty good place to hide a virus.
Also, creating a useful virus shorter than 1 KiB isn't as hard as it may sound from today's PoV - in fact, considering that floppy-based systems were a thing way into DOS 3 and the late 1980s, then being as short as possible is a must to be able to fit in.
Even more so because back then the main, if not the only means of infection was exchanging diskettes (*1). So to propagate it had to fit onto a disk - one often already filled. Which in turn adds a third reason: back then a 10 KiB virus would bite of a notable amount of disk space (*2), raising questions.
So taking all above into account, I wouldn't wonder if it had been done back then (*3).

Variant 1
A 'security' software can therefore not really check for file structure or anything fixed, as that would be version dependent for both DOS and BIOS/OEM release (*4). So since the entry is not a real one and its metadata not really useful (could be any date or time), a way too short length value might have been the only method they thought of as useful. Especially considering that early 'security' software was rarely more than length and pattern check.
So less of a brilliant solution and more like the only one possible without creating too many false alarms on diverging systems.
Variant #2
Another data point relevant here is that, AFAIR, 1 KiB is the cluster size on 360 KiB disks. Thus this might have been less a detection of a size of less than 1 KiB, but for pointing to a valid, chaining FAT entry - aka one not Zero (free cluster) nor EOF or special (i.e. 0FFxh on FAT12).
So essentially the simple assumption it must have a cluster chain. This need not have been some outright virus tool, but simply some file system consistency check.
Variant 3A
Beside being an intended check, this could quite well be a bug in some software, not necessarily a virus checker, trying to handle MSDOS.SYS circumventing DOS, which simply expects to find more than one cluster. Like one trying to patch some MSDOS code for whatever reason.
Variant #3B
Same as #3A except it really looks for some data between byte 512 and 1023, thus checking for having at least a second sector to read.

Either way, running such an old software on 6.22 - and many will (need to) reinstall old software after moving to a new OS - would have caused problems with a single cluster/shorter than 1 KiB MSDOS.SYS. This would also explain that Windows itself does not care for this as it assumes creating new disks will most likely not contain those old install files.
I wouldn't put it past Microsoft themselves to cause either #2 or #3 by having used such a 'utility' at some point together with some installation / language / whatsoever software. A classic move coming back to haunt later versions :)) - but that's rather speculative, as I do not remember such a situation (*5).

*1 - Overall, the threat profile back then was exchangeable media, thus way different from today's online source based one.
*2 - Average users back then really handled single file copy and maxing out usage, unlike today where 1 GiB free on a USB stick is already considered full.
*3 - I'm not enough of a virus researcher to know, so no definitive answer here.
*4 - Yes, there were OEM versions diverging far from MS's simple scheme, including loading loading MS-DOS as dedicated file. For example, on machines with no ROM BIOS (like Siemens PC-D and others) the boot ROM/sector would (only) load a BIOS file (which often already exceeded the 10 KiB of MS's loader) which then in turn would load the DOS file really using the directory entry.
*5 - Which of course, by conspirational logic, only proves that they have been successful in hiding it. <Clown_Emoji>

The 2024 April release of MS-DOS v4 shows that in this release msboot loads msload (first three sectors of msbio) which in turn loads the next stage of msbio (aka io.sys) and msbio loads msdos (aka msdos.sys) at a much later point. In the version of the release, the first cluster of io.sys must be cluster 2 of the file system, plus the msload 3 sectors at the start of io.sys need to be contiguous. (I think MS-DOS v5 lifted the "first cluster must be cluster 2" limitation.) Older versions than v4 might work more like you described with msboot loading both files.

@ecm Jep. True, that's why I explicit wrote early on . Such stuff is often dragged on over time. Also, that release is for MS-DOS 4.0, not 4.01, 4.0 is a complete rewritten OS, while 4.01 - the one commonly referred as DOS 4, is a modified 3.3, made by IBM. MS handed over the 3.x sources to IBM which continued to develop single user DOS. Also, the 20 sector load is part of the boot sector code. Not sure if that code modified ever, but I would think DOS 2 already needs more. Except the published code suggests different.

The standard cluster size for 1.44M disks was 512 bytes, so I really doubt 360K disks used 1K clusters.

@Raffzahn I think you're mistaking v4.00 (the release with sources) for the multitasking v4. The multitasking v4 was a rewrite. The v4.00 with sources is the one based on v3 ("v3.40"), and it is also the one which was developed into v4.01 later. I know because I collected the patches to exactly recreate both the v4.00 and v4.01 releases from the source tree. The rewrite, multitasking v4 ("v4.0-ozzie"), does not ship with complete sources: https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/tree/2d04cacc5322951f187bb17e017c12920ac8ebe2/v4.0-ozzie

@benrg true, 1.2 (Media type F9) and 1.44 (F9) uses 1 sector per cluster  (much like 160KiB of DOS1.x before) but 360 (FD) uses 2 sectors per cluster, like 2.88 (F0) later again. See this table for all details. The reason is the FAT provision. 360KiB Disks use 2 sectors per FAT, offering ~680 entries. Not enough to give each of the 720 sectors a cluster of it's own. 1.44 in turn use 9 sectors per FAT, offering ~3000 entries for its 2880 sector, so one sector per cluster works out fine.
